# Postgres Query has no desination for result data despite RETURN statement in function definition

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I've created a code that generates a HH:MM timestamp and saved it as a function. But when I try to call it with `SELECT random_timestamp();` an error is returned ->
**Query has no destination for result data**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_timestamp() 
RETURNS text AS 
'
BEGIN
SELECT
         CASE
                WHEN Length(s1.hours) = 1
                AND    Length(s1.minutes) = 1 THEN Concat(''0'',s1.hours, '':'',''0'', s1.minutes)
                WHEN Length(s1.hours) = 1
                AND    Length(s1.minutes) = 2 THEN Concat(''0'',s1.hours, '':'', s1.minutes)
                WHEN Length(s1.hours) = 2
                AND    Length(s1.minutes) = 1 THEN Concat(s1.hours, '':'', ''0'', s1.minutes)
                ELSE Concat(s1.hours, '':'', s1.minutes)
         END
  FROM   (SELECT floor(Random() * (23-0-1) + 0)::text AS hours ,
                 floor(random() * (59-0-1) + 0)::text AS minutes) AS s1;
RETURN(SELECT random_timestamp());
END;
' 
language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: 1) I would suggest going to dollar quoting per here [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) 2) You are not actually `RETURN`ing anything 3) Look here [Returning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html) 43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY 4) Start here [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) and read through all the sections at least once. It will answer many of your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect.

Corrected:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_timestamp() 
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare 
    v_return text; 
BEGIN
        SELECT
        CASE
                WHEN Length(s1.hours) = 1
                AND    Length(s1.minutes) = 1 THEN Concat('0',s1.hours, ':','0', s1.minutes)
                WHEN Length(s1.hours) = 1
                AND    Length(s1.minutes) = 2 THEN Concat('0',s1.hours, ':', s1.minutes)
                WHEN Length(s1.hours) = 2
                AND    Length(s1.minutes) = 1 THEN Concat(s1.hours, ':', '0', s1.minutes)
                ELSE Concat(s1.hours, ':', s1.minutes)
        end into v_return
        FROM   (SELECT floor(Random() * (23-0-1) + 0)::text AS hours ,
                 floor(random() * (59-0-1) + 0)::text AS minutes) AS s1;
        
        return v_return;
 
END;
$function$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need PL/pgSQL for this. A simple SQL function will do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_timestamp() 
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE sql
AS 
$function$
  SELECT
  CASE
      WHEN Length(s1.hours) = 1
      AND    Length(s1.minutes) = 1 THEN Concat('0',s1.hours, ':','0', s1.minutes)
      WHEN Length(s1.hours) = 1
      AND    Length(s1.minutes) = 2 THEN Concat('0',s1.hours, ':', s1.minutes)
      WHEN Length(s1.hours) = 2
      AND    Length(s1.minutes) = 1 THEN Concat(s1.hours, ':', '0', s1.minutes)
      ELSE Concat(s1.hours, ':', s1.minutes)
  end
  FROM   (SELECT floor(Random() * (23-0-1) + 0)::text AS hours ,
       floor(random() * (59-0-1) + 0)::text AS minutes) AS s1;
$function$
;
```

But you are over complicating this. If you want to generate a random time value, you can use:

```
select time '00:00' + make_interval(mins => (random() * 1440)::int)
```

You can put that into a function if you want:

```
create or replace function random_time()
   returns time
as
$$
  select time '00:00' + make_interval(mins => (random() * 1440)::int);
$$
language sql;
```

If you really need a `text` value, you can format that using `to_char()`

```
select to_char(random_time(), 'hh24:mi')
```

Of your